# problems with termination of scanning character after "space bar"

Tags: c, string, console

**When i enter a word i press space bar then I don't know why but i need to type one more word or a letter to stop scanning.**

```
    #include <stdio.h >
        char string1[20];
    char a='a', b='b', g='g', d='d', e='e', v='v', o='o';

    int i;
    int sum;

    printf (" my word is:\n");
    scanf( "%19s ", string1);
 sum=0;
       for (i = 0; string1[i] !='\0'; i++)
    {
    if (string1[i]==a ) {sum=  +1;} else
    if (string1[i]==b ) {sum=  +2;} else
    if (string1[i]==g ) {sum=  +3;} else
    if (string1[i]==d ) {sum=  +4;} else
    if (string1[i]==e ) {sum=  +5;} else
    if (string1[i]==v ) {sum=  +6;} else
    if (string1[i]==o ) {sum=  +50;} else
    {sum=0;} }
    printf ("%d\n" , sum);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please post actual code that at least compiles

Comment: why are u guys decreasing the note of my question

Comment: i cant its too long....

Comment: can you try this if it works ?

    `printf (" my Sentence is:\n");
    scanf( "%s %s\n ", string1,string2);`

Comment: no need for `\n` in scanf !

Comment: The trailing newline and space in the `scanf()` mean that you will have to type a non-blank after the word before the input terminates.  Using `scanf()` is — surprisingly or distressingly — hard; I essentially never use except on SO.  I'll read a line with `fgets()` and then use `sscanf()` to parse that — that works sanely.  But just `scanf()` and `fscanf()` is so problematic as to be unbearable (IMNSHO).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler could u use your comment as answer?

Comment: @GiorgiAzizGvimradze can you use getchar instead of scanf??

Comment: i entered getchar instead of scanf and i got the error:
Error 1 error C2660: 'getchar' : function does not take 2 arguments c:\users\gvimradze\desktop\alfabet\alfabet\alfabet.cpp 18 1 alfabet

Comment: @555k i think i have to include smth

Comment: @GiorgiAzizGvimradze: Treat my comment as if it were part of [teppic](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1627348/teppic)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15766630/15168); it already contains the core information (without the caustic commentary).  I've proffered my view that teaching beginners `scanf()` et al is one of the crueller things teachers can do elsewhere on SO.  One of the problems is that either teachers don't teach `if (scanf(...) != N)` or `n = scanf(...);` as the necessary way to invoke `scanf()` or students willfully and universally ignore this part of the teaching.

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf( "%s\n ", string1);
```

You're asking `scanf` to keep scanning until you type something other than whitespace after the word. To read just a word, use `%s` by itself.

Comment: how to let it stop scanning after "space bar"?

Comment: what can i do then? Must i write second word? and what if ill write more than 20 characters what will happen?

Comment: @GiorgiAzizGvimradze - if you just want one word, and everything after the space ignored, use `%s` by itself as I said. To specify a maximum number of characters, use something like `%10s`.

Comment: printf (" my word is:\n");
scanf( "%s ", string1);
it still needs another character after space bar to give me an answer

Comment: @GiorgiAzizGvimradze - when I say `"%s"` by itself, I don't mean `"%s "` :)

Comment: Spaces matter.  Details matter in programming.

Comment: is it possible to force it stop scanning after my "space bar"

Comment: @GiorgiAzizGvimradze Usually, input is only available after Return has been pressed. If you read the input unbuffered, `"%s"` stops scanning when you type a space.

Comment: @GiorgiAzizGvimradze: `scanf( "%s", string1);` will copy everything you type up to the space into `string1`.

Comment: it does, but i must type any word or a character after space to terminate operation or let it start calculating